# Запись динамического массива в бинарный файл c++

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь функцию, которая будет создавать BMP файл.

Основные структуры:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
    typedef struct {
        int16_t bfType;
        uint32_t bfSize;
        int16_t bfReserved1;
        int16_t bfReserved2;
        uint32_t bfOffBits;
    } BITMAPFILEHEADER;
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push, 1)
    typedef struct {
        uint32_t biSize;
        int32_t biWidth;
        int32_t biHeight;
        int16_t biPlanes;
        int16_t biBitCount;
        uint32_t biCompression;
        uint32_t biSizeImage;
        int32_t biXPelsPerMeter;
        int32_t biYPelsPerMeter;
        uint32_t biClrUsed;
        uint32_t biClrImportant;
    } BITMAPINFOHEADER;
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push, 1)
    typedef struct {
        int8_t rgbBlue;
        int8_t rgbGreen;
        int8_t rgbRed;
        int8_t rgbAplha;
    } RGBQUAD;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Сами переменные и функция:

```
BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh;
BITMAPINFOHEADER bih;
RGBQUAD* palette;
void Create(const char* fname) {

    ofstream out(fname, ios::binary);
    palette = new RGBQUAD[16];
    //Здесь пропустил заполнение палитры напишу, но заполнял для теста вот так = new RGBQUAD[16]{ {255,255,255,0}, {}};
    bfh = {};
    bih = {};
    bfh.bfType = 0x4d42;
    out.write((const char*)&bfh, sizeof(bfh));
    out.write((const char*)&bih, sizeof(bih));

    //Тут я перепробовал много вариантов, но ни один не работал.
}
```

Как записать в бинарный файл палитру? Если сделать ее статическим массивом и написать

> out.write((const char*)&test, sizeof(test));

то все будет работать идеально, но все же нужен динамический массив. Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать, то что мне нужно и для понимания буду рад если объясните, как это работает.

Вот пример:

```
palette = new RGBQUAD[16]{
        {0,0,0,0}, {0, 128,0,0}, {0, 0, 128, 0}, {0,128,128,0},
        {0,0,0,128},{0,128,0,128},{0,0,128,128},{0,128,128,128},
        {0,192,192,192}, {0,255,0,0},{0,0,255,0},{0,255,255,0},
        {0,0,0,255}, {0,255,0,255}, {0,0,255,255}, {0, 255, 255, 255}
    };
out.write((const char*)palette, sizeof(RGBQUAD) * 16);
```

А вот, что получается (извиняюсь за качество):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очевидно это не то, что я ожидал увидеть.

Я посмотрел и оказывается, что palette инициализируется не так, как я указал а все элементы равны -51. Не знаю пока что в чем дело.

Comment: Поделить этими вариантами, а то не понятно что именно у Вас не работало. Я конечно предполагаю что размер у динамического массива Вы пытались получить точно так же как у массива на стеке, но лучше дополните свой вопрос.

Comment: Попробуйте например такой вариант `palette = new RGBQUAD[2]{{255, 255, 255, 0},{255, 255, 255, 0}};` и попробуйте занести в бинарный файл этот массив чтобы получилось 8 байтов. `ff ff ff 00 ff ff ff 00` если получилось без ошибок, то смело напишите ваш код в виде ответа и 99%, что это то что мне нужно)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не в записи, а в инициализации массива структур c помощью initializer list, а это уже интересно, т.к я так же думал что такая конструкция должна работать..

[image: Отладка кода]

Comment: Да я уже понял в чем проблема, но все же как ее решить?

Comment: похоже на баг компилятора vc, в gcc этот же код работает https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/CigpPm

Comment: да, народ в телеге подтвердил, это это баг vc) https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/816869/aggregate-initialization-is-not-performed-on-dynam.html